# The best way to catch IntegrityError on admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to catch IntegrityError in admin.py file, but cannot do it properly. Is there a way at all? Note, that I use UniqueConstraint for my recipe model, since I do not want duplicated tags and ingredients.

For many to many fields in my Recipe Admin model I've used inliners. IntegrityError is raised when I specially try to create a recipe with two identical tags.

```
from recipes.models import (
    Recipe, Ingredient, Tag, RecipeIngredient, RecipeTag
)

from django.contrib import admin


class RecipeIngredientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Recipe.ingredients.through


class RecipeTagInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Recipe.tags.through


class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    readonly_fields=('total_favorites',)
    list_filter = ('tags',)
    inlines = (RecipeIngredientInline, RecipeTagInline)

    @admin.display(empty_value='---empty---')
    def total_favorites(self, obj):
        return obj.userrecipe_set.all().count()

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Here I am trying to catch the exception, but without joy.
        breakpoint()
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)


class IngredientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    list_filter = ('measurement_unit',)


class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    list_filter = ('slug',)


class RecipeIngredientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('recipe__name',)


class RecipeTagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('recipe__name',)


admin.site.register(Recipe, RecipeAdmin)
admin.site.register(Ingredient, IngredientAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
admin.site.register(RecipeIngredient, RecipeIngredientAdmin)
admin.site.register(RecipeTag, RecipeTagAdmin)
```

Comment: try/except block just does not want to work - it raises an IntegrityError anyway.

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace of the error?